# Сделать стрелку :after шире

Tags: html, css

Есть css:

```
.custom-select::after {
    content: "˅";
  padding: 12px 8px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  top: 8px;
  z-index: 1;
  text-align: center;
  width: 10%;
  height: 100%;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

он создает стрелку:

[image]

Сама стрелка сплющенная, а нужно, чтобы наоборот была широкая. Как это сделать?

Comment: Не использовать вместо стрелки символ, а взять нормальную картинку, и вставлять через `background`

Answer (score 2):

```css
p {
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    border-top: 5px solid black;
    border-left: 5px solid black;
    transform: rotate(224deg);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p class="text"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Это должна быть стрелка в селекте, а не сама по себе, так что тэг `p` не подойдет)

Comment: @Alex, вам ничего не мешает заменить `p` на `::after`

Answer (score 2):

Если проблема лишь в пропорциях символа, то вполне можно это подправить с помощью `transform: scale()`:

```css
.custom-select::after {
  content: '˅';
  padding: 12px 8px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  top: 8px;
  z-index: 1;
  text-align: center;
  width: 10%;
  height: 100%;
  pointer-events: none;
  
  transform: scalex(2);
}
```

```html
<div class="custom-select"></div>
```